# Unable to Pip Install Magenda

Tags: pip

I am trying to install the `magenda` library with `pip`, but I got this error from the system:

```
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.     
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [18 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])       
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^       
        File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 149, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\82102\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-xrg_vn9w\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 366, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\82102\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-xrg_vn9w\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 480, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend, self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "C:\Users\82102\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-xrg_vn9w\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 358, in <module>
        File "<string>", line 94, in get_ext_modules
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.distutils'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.     
hint: See above for details.
```

What do you think the issue is?